# How to put a derivation as a boundary in "scipy.optimize.curve_fit"

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to get the coefficients of a function p(T,x). I provided the data for p, T and x from excel sheets via panda. The following Code works quite nice for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./Data.xlsx"))

T = np.array(df['T'], dtype=float)
x = np.array(df['x'], dtype=float)
p = np.array(df['p'], dtype=float)
p_s = 67.17 

def func(X, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    T, x = X
    return x * p_s + x * (1 - x) * (a + b * T + c * T ** 2 + d * x + e * x * T + f * x * T ** 2) * p_s

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (T, x), p)
print("a = %s , b = %s, c = %s, d = %s, e = %s, f = %s" % (popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4], popt[5]))
```

My acutal problem is, that the function is swinging a little bit in the end. [image: plot of function]

Because of this behaviour i get two `x` values for one `p` value, which i dont want.
So to avoid this little swing i want to accomplish a boundary condition for the fitting that say something like `dp/dx (for constant T) > 0`. With `dp/dx` I mean the derivation of the function after `x`.

Is this possible with the normal `bound` paramter of `curve_fit`? How can I do this?

EDIT:

As suggested I've messed a little bit around with `least_square` function but I guess that I came to a point where I don't realy understand what I'm doing or have to do.

```
T = np.array(df['T'], dtype=float)
x = np.array(df['x'], dtype=float)
p = np.array(df['p'], dtype=float)
p_s = 67

def f(X, z):
    T, x = X
    return x * p_s + x * (1 - x) * (z[0] + z[1] * T + z[2] * T ** 2 + z[3] * x + z[4] * x * T + z[5] * x * T ** 2) * p_s

def g(X,p,z):
    return p - f(X ,z)

z0 = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype=float)

res, flag = least_squares(g,z0, args=(T,x,p))
print(res)
```

With this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: g() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: `bound` will specify the upper and lower bounds for your parameter results, but will not guarantee a monotonic behaviour unless you know beforehand under which boundaries you need your parameters. I reckon you may set it as a `scipy.optimize.minimize` problem (least squares), using a `derivative` condition as a constraint function. Can you show the data and the curve_fit in the same plot?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I've edited my question.